# The two UITableViews error

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an app with two UITableViews in the same view. The problem is that when I set the two datasources and delegates to the view controller, the app crashes. This only works with one table view, not with both. Any ideas?

Comment: If it's crashing when you set the delegate/datasource the pointer to your table view may be dereferenced. First try setting a breakpoint and checking it's value but it's hard to help without more information.

Comment: OK I don't know why now it works well... I think it crashed for the iPad 5 simulator that is a @!$#!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work for any number of TableViews. In delegates methods you should process each table separately.